# Dual of $n$-cosheaf is an $n$-sheaf?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

For a site $\mathcal{C}$, an $n$-cosheaf is a functor $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow $n$\text{-}\mathfrak{Cat}$ such that for any cover $(U_i\rightarrow U)_i$, we have
$$\prod_{i,j}\mathcal{F}(U_i\times_U U_j)\rightrightarrows \prod_i \mathcal{F}(U_i)\rightarrow \mathcal{F}(U)$$
is an $n$-pushout. Does it then follow that the contravariant functor
$$H_{\mathcal{F}}:\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow n\text{-}\mathfrak{Cat},\quad X\mapsto \text{Hom}_{n\text{-}\mathfrak{Cat}}(\mathcal{F}(X),\mathfrak{C})$$
is a $n$-sheaf, where $\mathfrak{C}$ is a $n$-category? Basically what I'm asking is if the "$n$-Hom" functor sends pushouts to pullbacks.

The case I'm most interested in is that of cosheaves of $\infty$-groupoids and groupoids.

Comment: Yes, Homs send colimits to limits always.

Comment: I agree with Qiaochu, modulo the fact that your definition of an $n$-cosheaf is wrong. The right definition of a sheaf valued in an $\infty$-category $C$ says that for any cover $U_\bullet \to U$, we have that $\mathcal F(U)$ is canonically equivalent to the $\infty$-categorical limit of the functor $\Delta \to C$, $[n] \mapsto \prod_{i_0,\dots,i_n} \mathcal F(U_{i_0} \times_U \cdots \times_U U_{i_n})$. If $C$ is an $n+1$-category like $Cat_n$, then I believe you can truncate this simplicial object at level $n+1$ and still get things right. Cosheaves should be defined by the analogous colimit.